# Создание подключения к БД [ООП php]

Tags: php, база-данных, pdo

Начал разбираться с ООП php, а именно с архитектурой MVC.
Возник вопрос по подключению к бд. В одном из уроков на данную тему,в модели в функциях взаимодействующих с бд вызывается функция создания объекта PDO, то есть при нескольких действиях с бд на одной странице, создается несколько несколько объектов PDO. Как мне кажется это не правильно. А лучше создать одно подключение и пользоваться им до выполнения всего кода. Но как и в каком месте вызывать данное подключение? 
Создавать в фронт конроллере или роутере? - но ведь не на каждой странице нужно подключение к бд.
Была мысль проверять наличие созданного подключения и если его нет создавать его, но возникли проблемы с видимостью переменной из функций одной модели в функциях другой.
В общем как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы столкнулись с паттерном **Синглтон** - созданием единого екземпляра класса БД. Такой объект не создаётся каждый раз, лишь единожды. И далее при обращении к классу проверяется наличие объекта и если он создан - отдаётся, новый не создаётся. В случае с БД его используют очень часто.

```
class Singleton{

  private static $instance = null;
  private static $i = 0;
  /**
   * @return Singleton
   */
  public static function getInstance(){
    if (null === self::$instance){
        self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }


  private function __wakeup(){}
  private function __clone(){}
  private function __construct(){}
}

$obj = Singleton::getInstance();
```